# using javascript to add form fields.. but below, not to the side?

Tags: javascript, html, field

So as I click the button, the javascript adds new fields. Currently it adds the new text box to the side.. is there a way to make it add below? I guess as if there were a 
.
Here is the code. Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var instance = 1;

        function newTextBox(element)
        {       
            instance++; 
            var newInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
            newInput.id = "text" + instance;
            newInput.name = "text" + instance;
            newInput.type = "text";
            //document.body.write("<br>");
            document.body.insertBefore(newInput, element);
        }
    </script>
</head>


<body>
    <input id="text2" type="text" name="text1"/> <br>
    <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="New text box" onclick="newTextBox(this);" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Insert a `<br/>` tag infront of the inserted input or better yet, put the input into a div and control the look of it with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the end of your function:

```
document.body.insertBefore(document.createElement("br"), element);
```

Full code:

```
<html>
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                var instance = 1;

                function newTextBox(element)
                {               
                        instance++; 
                        var newInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
                        newInput.id = "text" + instance;
                        newInput.name = "text" + instance;
                        newInput.type = "text";
                        //document.body.write("<br>");
                        document.body.insertBefore(newInput, element);

                        document.body.insertBefore(document.createElement("br"), element);
                }
        </script>
</head>


<body>
        <input id="text2" type="text" name="text1"/> <br>
        <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="New text box" onclick="newTextBox(this);" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `<br>` element the same way and put it between.

```
var newBr = document.createElement("BR");
document.body.insertBefore(newBr, element);
```

Or use CSS. The `display:block` *may* be of value.

Answer (score 0):

You could either, insert `br` element after the new input, or wrap it inside a `div` element:

```
function newTextBox(element) {                
    instance++; 
    var newInput = document.createElement("INPUT"); 
    newInput.id = "text" + instance; 
    newInput.name = "text" + instance; 
    newInput.type = "text"; 

    var div = document.createElement('div'); 
    div.appendChild(newInput); 
    document.body.insertBefore(div, element); 
}
```

Check the above example [here](http://jsbin.com/iqoja).