# add more field in certain page

Tags: java, php, wamp, field

I have a page that consist of child information like, `family type`, `name`, `gender`, `date of birth`, `country of birth`.

code

```
    <td colspan="2" class="title_all_u">Family Member 2 (Child)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="50%" class="pk">Family Type</td>
              <td width="50%" class="pk_2"><input name="family_child_type" type="text" class="textfield_word" id="family_child_type" value="<?php echo $family_child_type ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="pk">Name</td>
              <td width="50%" class="pk_2"><input name="family_child_name" type="text" class="textfield_word" id="family_child_name" value="<?php echo $family_child_name ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="pk">Gender Key</td>
              <td class="pk_2">
              <input type="radio" name="family_child_gender" id="family_child_gender" value="Male" <?php if ($family_child_gender=="Male"){ ?> checked <?php } ?>/>
               Male   &nbsp;  
               <input type="radio" name="family_child_gender" id="family_child_gender" value="Female" <?php if ($family_child_gender=="Female"){ ?> checked <?php } ?> />
              Female
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="pk">Date of Birth</td>
              <td class="pk_2"><input name="family_child_date_birth" type="text" class="tcal" id="family_child_date_birth" value="<?php echo date_create($family_child_date_birth)->format('d-m-Y');?>" readonly="readonly"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="pk">Country of Birth</td>
              <td class="pk_2">
              <?php
                $query = "SELECT country_type FROM country";
                $result = mysql_query ($query); ?>
                <select name="family_child_country" >
                <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['country_type']?>"  <?php if ( $family_child_country ==  $row['country_type']){ ?> selected <?php } ?>>
                <?php echo $row['country_type']?></option>
                <?php }?>
                </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="pk">Nationality</td>
              <td class="pk_2">
                <?php
                $query = "SELECT nationality_type FROM nationality";
                $result = mysql_query ($query); ?>
                <select name="family_child_nationality" >
                <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['nationality_type']?>"  <?php if ( $family_child_nationality ==  $row['nationality_type']){ ?> selected <?php } ?>>
                <?php echo $row['nationality_type']?></option>
                <?php }?>
                </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="pk">IC Number</td>
              <td width="50%" class="pk_2"><input name="family_child_ic_num" type="text" class="textfield_word" id="family_child_ic_num" value="<?php echo $family_child_ic_num ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="pk">Passport No.</td>
              <td width="50%" class="pk_2"><input name="family_child_pass_num" type="text" class="textfield_word" id="family_child_pass_num" value="<?php echo $family_child_pass_num ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="pk">Education/Training</td>
              <td width="50%" class="pk_2"><input name="family_child_education" type="text" class="textfield_word" id="family_child_education" value="<?php echo $family_child_education ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="pk">Handicapped</td>
              <td width="50%" class="pk_2"><input name="family_child_handicaped" type="text" class="textfield_word" id="family_child_handicaped" value="<?php echo $family_child_handicaped ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="pk">Child Custody</td>
              <td width="50%" class="pk_2"><input name="family_child_custody" type="text" class="textfield_word" id="family_child_custody" value="<?php echo $family_child_custody ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="pk">Married</td>
               <td class="pk_2">
               <input type="radio" name="family_child_married_status" id="family_child_married_status" value="Yes" <?php if ($family_child_married_status=="Yes"){ ?> checked <?php } ?>/>
               Yes   &nbsp;  
               <input type="radio" name="family_child_married_status" id="family_child_married_status" value="No" <?php if ($family_child_married_status=="No"){ ?> checked <?php } ?> />
              No  </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="pk">Employed</td>
              <td width="50%" class="pk_2"><input name="family_child_employed" type="text" class="textfield_word" id="family_child_employed" value="<?php echo $family_child_employed ?>" />
<input type="button"  size="3" cols="30" value="Add Child" onClick="addNew()">
</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
```

but if I have more than 1 child, how can I add new field within the same page that allow me to key in my 2nd or 3rd child information?

Comment: you need a form with variable number of fields, right?

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631786/forms-with-a-variable-number-of-fields][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631786/forms-with-a-variable-number-of-fields

Comment: @tinyByte yes. but in my case, maybe create a 'add' button so I can add my 2nd or 3rd child information. only when I click the 'add' button, the field will appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to add more text fields dynamically by providing a button or link with the title "add more", and when this link is clicked a new field is added to the form below the child field, the code in this question can help: [Add more text fields dynamically in new line (html)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224823/add-more-text-fields-dynamically-in-new-line-html)

Comment: another related question is this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080937/using-javascript-to-add-form-fields-but-what-will-the-new-name-be

Comment: but in my situation, when I click add button, will appear 2nd child field with all the contain like, name field, gender, date of birth.

Comment: I didn't get it, you want the whole form to be created again, or just a few new fields? In case a few specific fields, mention them.

Comment: whole field e.g. <td width="50%" class="pk">Family Type</td> , <td class="pk">Name</td>, <td class="pk">Gender Key</td> and the others. just with clicking 'add child' button